# What does the padlock icon next to a name mean in staff management?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

[image]

I've just started looking at the staff management side of MGSV TPP and noticed a few staff members have a padlock and person icon next to their name.  What is locked and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it means that staff are working under a direct contact and can not be fired or reassigned.

Comment: If I remember correctly it also means that they can't be taken away if your base is attacked. I always put the best guys I have under direct contract.

Comment: @Christian Yes, that is the primary motive behind the direct contract and why it's limited. You're supposed to put your best staff under direct contract so you don't lose them.

Comment: I can't remember where I read that staff under direct contract will not participate in FOB battles at all. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @PhilD. I think I saw it in a tip after pressing Select. Or maybe it’s part of the help you see by pressing Select while on the iDroid’s Staff Management screen.